# If a neural network is a function f that maps x to y then is it correct to say that $f:R^x \rightarrow R^y$?

Tags: vector-spaces, real-numbers, machine-learning, neural-networks

I can say that a simple neural network can be formally defined as $ f: R^D \to R^L$ where $D$ is the size of the input vector $x$ and $L$ the size of the output vector $y$. So I can say that $y = f(x)$.

Now I wonder whether it would also be correct to state the following:

$f: R^x \to R^y$

Would that be formally also correct given the information above? I want to express that this function $f$ maps an input $x \in R^{10}$ to an output $y \in R^{3}$. Is it understandable and formally correct that I want to express with $R^{x}$ that the input is of the dimension like $x$?

Comment: Use $\mathbb{R}$ (```$\mathbb{R}$```) to denote the real numbers. And no. It would be correct to say $x \in \mathbb{R}^D, y \in \mathbb{R}^L, f:\mathbb{R}^D \to \mathbb{R}^L$.

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks for your fast reply. But I could say it this way: $f: \mathbb{R}^{D_x} \to \mathbb{R}^{D_y}$ where $D_x$ denotes the dimensionality of x from the input space and $D_y$ from the output space. So correct?

Comment: That would be fine, yes. $\dim \operatorname{dom} (x)$ would be even clearer.

Comment: @K.defaoite how would I use dim dom(x)? It means dimension of domain x, right?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant dim dom(f).